# spark OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using spark 2.4.1 version.
Even after increasing memory and number of partition size it is giving OOM.
my job was working earlier but I changed/used "ds.cache()" but have not unpersisted() those.
Does it have any impact ?
Now small data set is also not working.

Where and how to check what is causing problem?

Below is the stack trace.

```
org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.get(ApplicationCache.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.withSparkUI(ApplicationCache.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$HistoryServer$$loadAppUi(HistoryServer.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$1.doGet(HistoryServer.scala:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:513)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:493)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```